# how to, on submit form gives duplicate in the serialized string using jQuery and jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, json, forms, jquery-mobile, serialization

i have a simple page with a simple form:

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="add_form">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
            <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
            <button data-role="button" id="cancel-form" >Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).on( "pageshow", "#main", function() {
    new MAIN();
});


var MAIN = (function () {
    function MAIN() {
        $("#add_form").submit(function(){
            console.log($(this).serialize());
            return false;
        });
    }

    return MAIN;
})();
```

the issue is that i get `name=&name=test&description=&description=some content`,

basically duplicates in the serialized string..

On the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) page it says:

```
Warning: selecting both the form and its children will cause duplicates in the serialized string.
```

but i am not doing that, am i?

Any ideas on this issue?

edit:

i found a solution that kind of works

```
var MAIN = (function () {
    function MAIN() {
        var _this = this;
        $("#add_form").submit(function(){
            console.log(_this.serializeObject($(this).serializeArray()));
            return false;
        });
    }

    MAIN.prototype.serializeObject = function(a) {
        var o = {};
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name]) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };

    return MAIN;
})();
```

this will console.log `Object {name: "werwerwer", description: "erewwewerwerw"}`

Comment: Why are you using the complicated double definition of `MAIN`?  It buys you nothing but unnecessary complication.  Remove the outer self executing function.  It is not adding anything.  Also, why are you using `new Main()` instead of just `Main()`?

Comment: Seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/crf7y/

Comment: @jfriend00, i am using `MAIN` for other things too, as a class, this is just a working sample

Comment: @ArunPJohny, it sems to work there, maybe there is a problem with the way i load my view

Comment: Can you check `console.log($("#add_form").length)` and `console.log($("#add_form" :input))`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, the first one returns 1 the second one returns the dom object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var MAIN = (function () {
    function MAIN() {
        var _this = this;
        $("#add_form").submit(function(){
            console.log(_this.serializeObject($(this).serializeArray()));
            return false;
        });
    }

    MAIN.prototype.serializeObject = function(a) {
        var o = {};
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name]) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };

    return MAIN;
})();
```